# MySQL: What would be the upper datetime limit '2017-05-31 23:59:59' or '2017-05-31 24:00:00'?

Tags: mysql

what should I use when setting upper limit of duration

a) `date_start between '2017-05-01 00:00:00' and '2017-05-31 23:59:59'`

b) `date_start between '2017-05-01 00:00:00' and '2017-05-31 24:00:00'`

is it a or b?

Thanks

Comment: For clarity, wouldn't you want to use the same scale for both ends of the range?

Comment: i've added `HH:ii:ss` in start date `'2017-05-01 00:00:00'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will be `a`

```
date_start between '2017-05-01' and '2017-05-31 23:59:59'
```

because

```
2017-05-31 24:00:00
means
2017-06-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: 24 does not mean 0. 24 is an invalid time, and, if it means anything at all, means NULL.